# How to use a source code line to slice the llvm IR code?

Tags: llvm-ir

I have a C source code and also its llvm bit code. Please tell me how to slice the bitcode if I give a particular line from the source code as slicing target. I am actually trying to get the branch and jump instructions or their line numbers in bit code which will allow the program to reach that block where this source code line is present in bit code format. Please tell me if it is possible at all.

Comment: Does slicing mean extracting out a portion of code as a function?

Comment: @DTharun Here slicing means extracting the bit code which are necessary to reach the target line and the bitcode will not have any other code. It is basically a control dependent lines of code that will directly reach the target line.

Comment: If I understood properly, the portion of code in llvm-ir corresponding to c source is what you call a slice. It is not always possible to get IR code for c source because the compiler optimizes. If you are fine without optimizations, you can try tracing them with debug information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get LLVM bitcode line number from CPP source code line number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57387315/how-to-get-llvm-bitcode-line-number-from-cpp-source-code-line-number)